# How to get index in jstl display table

Tags: jstl

I have display table like below

```
<display:table name="sample" id="sample" class="display-table" style="width:100%;">

</display:table>
```

Now I want to get index of loop like for first element 0 for second 1 and 2,3,4... go on. How it is possible with display table.

For just reference we can do like this in JSTL forEach loop with help of varStatus variable like below

```
<c:forEach items="${sample}" var="clm" varStatus="status">
     ${status.index}
</c:forEach>
```

So is this possible with display table?

Comment: Are referring to the column by this statement `index of loop` ?

Comment: see to this [**link**](http://www.displaytag.org/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html) it may help you

Comment: I have already referred it. It doesn't helps me.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `offset` attribute specified there ?

Comment: Try and find out by your self what is purpose of that. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

display table tag implicitly exposes row number named id_rowNum where id is specified in display table tag.

In your scenario:

```
    <display:table name="sample" id="sample" class="display-table" style="width:100%;">
        <display:column title="Row Number" >
          <c:out value="${sample_rowNum - 1}"/>
        </display:column>
        ...
    </display:table>
```

Also make sure to include core tag as:

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

You can find more information about implicit objects of display table tag [here](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_implicitobjects.html).

Comment: Great dude.. I Wished if I can get this solution before. But really thanks for showing this solution.

Comment: with java it's <%String numLigne = pageContext.getAttribute("sample_rowNum").toString();  %> Allowing for dynamic value of the id